# mysql query for UPDATE with second table having multiple records

Tags: sql, mysql

i have two tables where i need to update first table from the second table record.
Second table has multiple rows for the join, i need the latest date to be updated to the first table.
I have the following query but it locks the database. First table has more than 42K records while second table has 400K records.

```
UPDATE first_table ar
    INNER JOIN second_table fc
        ON fc.atid = ar.atid
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT atid, MAX(recordingdate) maxDate
        FROM second_table WHERE recordingdate > '1900-01-01' 
        GROUP BY atid LIMIT 10
    ) b ON fc.atid = b.atid AND
            fc.recordingdate = b.maxDate
SET ar.recordingdate = fc.recordingdate 
WHERE ar.recordingdate IS NULL;
```

The sub query runs very quickly but when running the whole update, the server throws 500 error and is not able to complete the update even with the `LIMIT`.

Comment: "the server throws 500 error" - what do you mean by that? MySQL does not use that error code. Sounds like a PHP problem? If yes, what does the error message **really** contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use multiple inner joins. This should be enough.

```
UPDATE first_table ar
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT atid, MAX(recordingdate) maxDate
        FROM second_table WHERE recordingdate > '1900-01-01' 
        GROUP BY atid
    ) b ON ar.atid = b.atid
SET ar.recordingdate = b.maxDate 
WHERE ar.recordingdate IS NULL;
```

Comment: Works well, for 401916 rows the query took 373.5751 seconds